# Java Resource errors

Tags: java, android, xml

We are having a resource error when we try to run our code.

```
package com.example.searchtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class GoogleSearchIntentActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editTextInput;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextInput);
    }

    public void onSearchClick(View v)
    {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            String term = editTextInput.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, term);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dp">

    <edittext
        android:id="@+id/editTextInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter search text">

        <requestfocus>
        </requestfocus></edittext>

    <button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onclick="onSearchClick"
        android:layout_margintop="10dp">


    </button></linearlayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.searchtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".GoogleSearchIntentActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

these are our mainActivity.java, activity_main.xml, and AndroidManifest.xml codes from our app.

The error is within our `public class GoogleSearchIntentActivity extends Activity`

We are high school students trying to create an image search app for our computer science capstone class, we have been trying to fix this error without success, and our teacher is completely clueless.

Comment: Post logcat details, to check at which line the error is.

Comment: and what is the actual error?

Comment: well we fixed the error we were having, but now the app crashes when we try to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components in your xml file must have a first capitalized letter.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter search text">

        <requestFocus>
        </requestFocus></EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onclick="onSearchClick"
        android:layout_margintop="10dp">


    </Button></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not that they all need a first capitalized letter. They just need to be spelled correctly, case-sensitively. You've still got some typos there; `EditText`, `requestFocus`.